# asp.net mvc save user selection globally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a mvc 5 web application which allow user to select language and currency to be displayed to them, in which the choice of language and currency they selected is expected to be retrievable throughout the controller and view.

Do note that the user i referring here is anonymous user (which is user that do not log in) so i do not intend to save their selection to database.

I am thinking of using session to store the selection. However, it seems not a good choice of to me as these are only two values that i need to store in session. Is there any other better alternative?

Comment: Session is totally fine in my humble oppinion. These are 2 small values you'll store and if you haven't fiddled around too much, this session will eventually time out; on the other hand you could use cookies.

Comment: Don't use session, use a cookie.

Comment: It comes down to one of three options: session, which doesn't scale easily; cookie, which the user can disable; or storing in the web page (either as hidden fields or as part of the URL).  Each have good and bad options.

Comment: i see. is there an approach call global viewbag?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to put language in url

{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}

e.g.

en/home/index

fr/home/index

Advantage is that the url is bookmarkable and clearer

An example implementation: http://adamyan.blogspot.sg/2010/07/addition-to-aspnet-mvc-localization.html

For currency, I'll probably determine it from the culture of user, or at least use that value as default for first time user. If you want to let user be able to change it, cookie is fine in my opinion.